# Python / IronPython logging : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'f_back'

Tags: python, logging, ironpython

When collections.OrderedDict() is instantiated in an IronPython script, I get the following:

```
System.MissingMemberException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'f_back'
at logging$33.findCaller$1681(PythonFunction $function, Object self) in C:\Python26\Lib\logging\__init__.py:line     1101
at logging$33._log$1683(PythonFunction $function, Object self, Object level, Object msg, Object args, Object         exc_info, Object extra) in C:\Python26\Lib\logging\__init__.py:line 1129
at logging$33.info$1675(PythonFunction $function, Object self, Object msg, Object args, Object kwargs) in        C:\Python26\Lib\logging\__init__.py:line 1021
```

The script calling this works fine on other Windows boxes, only occurs on my box. I'm not familiar with the logging functionality at all - can anyone shed some light?

**Python version 2.6**

**IronPython Version 2.7.1**

Many thanks

Comment: I suspect this is an exception thrown during exception handling, where the traceback frame objects do not have a `.f_back` reference to the previous frame in the traceback. You may want to step through the code with a debugger to see what error is being masked here.

Comment: I don't know anything about IronPython, but could it be possible that IronPython is trying to get OrderedDict from regular python's collections module?  If so, `OrderedDict` wouldn't be there because it was added in python2.7 ... (It would seem pretty fishy if that was the problem though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the library from Python 2.6 with IronPython 2.7. You should use IronPython 2.7's standard library instead, which has a bunch of fixes and workarounds that make it work (not perfect, but a lot better).

For example, I get the following on IronPython 2.7.3:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict()
>>> od[1] = 2
>>> od[0] = 4
>>> od
OrderedDict([(1, 2), (0, 4)])
>>>
```

Most likely you set the `IRONPYTHONPATH` variable to have Python's Lib before IronPython's Lib. That used to be required (for IronPython < 2.6), but now it's not recommended.

Comment: Thank you sir, you pointed me in the right direction. You were right to suggest that the Python path preceded the IronPython path in IRONPYTHONPATH. I found that swapping their order was necessary, but not sufficient. I had to add "\Lib" to C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7.1 in the environment variable, and then the probably went away. If you could explain why this is the case, I would be grateful.

Comment: You should be able to just get rid of the environment variable if the only thing it has are the IronPython and Python Lib paths. IronPython will automatically pick up its own stdlib, but if IRONPYTHONPATH is set it uses that instead.